# Stacking div elements within adjusting container

Tags: css, html

I am having some troubles on how to structure a new widget I am working on. I am trying to implement a geographic map that contains some hotspots, just like an old school image map. However, for various purposes, I want to accomplish it without the use of image maps.

So far, I have gotten to this incomplete solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/nielsbuus/FZJ8E/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <!-- I'm a container, I need to expand in height, when my children expand, so they don't overlap elements beneath me. Sort of like clearing floats -->
    <div class="lower">
        <!-- I contain an image. My width is fixed, but my height may vary. -->
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/300/325" />
    </div>
    <div class="higher-container">
        <div style="top: 20px; left: 30px" class="higher-spot">foo</div>
        <div style="top: 80px; left: 50px" class="higher-spot">bar</div>
        <div style="top: 85px; left: 70px" class="higher-spot">baz</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="successor">
  Please keep me below all of this.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent {
    background-color: #ccffff;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
}

.lower {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 0;
}

.higher-container {
    position: absolute;    
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.3);
}

.higher-spot {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
    z-index: 1px;
}

.successor {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

The main problem here is the use of absolutely positioned z-indexed divs. They detach from the rest of the layout, causing the parent container to not expand, thereby placing succeeding elements beneath the absolutely positioned elements.

I am looking for ideas on how to stack two divs (lower and higher-container) on top of each other and have the parent container expand to the size of the lower div.

Comment: Just wondering, what made you not choose my answer, which is basically the same but came earlier?

Comment: I voted up both answers. In addition to a solution, rgthrees answer also contains a code example and a link to a jsfiddle which demonstrates a working implementation.

Comment: My solution contained also a link to the jsfiddle demonstrating the implementation, and had described the changes required in your code to make it work. Anyways, nevermind :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only need one of your children to be absolutely positioned: the one that is placed on top (`.higher-container`). This way, `.lower` which will always be taller than `.higher-container` will stretch the parent container normally, then the `higher-container` will be layers, aboslutely, on top. We just need to add a `top` and `left` positioning to it:

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/M6jm8/

```
.lower {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 0;
}

.higher-container {
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;   
    z-index:1;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you are using `position: absolute` on your `.lower` container. Use it as `relative` and then give a `top: 0` rule to the `.higher-container`.

[<kbd>**Updated fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FZJ8E/2/)